# Can you step out of the airport for some time while transiting through Casablanca Airport?

Tags: transit, indian-citizens, casablanca

We are traveling to Monrovia from Nairobi (Royal Air Maroc). We've got Indian Passports with business visas. We have our connecting flight from Casablanca to Monrovia. Can we step out of the airport for some time in Casablanca? We have about 8 hours between flights.

Answer (score 3):

No, to enter Morocco you'd need a Moroccan transit visa, according to the IATA database used by Airlines.

Comment: [Timatic link](https://www.timaticweb.com/cgi-bin/tim_website_client.cgi?SpecData=1&VISA=&page=visa&NA=IN&TR=CMN&DE=ROB&AR=00&PASSTYPES=PASS&user=KLMB2C&subuser=KLMB2C), courtesy KLM.

Comment: @choster He's *entering* Morocco though - TWOV=not leaving the transit area

Comment: It was meant to be in support of your answer; I don't think it contradicts it.

Answer (score 2):

What you will need is a Transit visa. Unfortunately citizens with Indian passports will need a Tourist, Business or Transit Visa in order to enter Marocco.

Answer (score 0):

It depend on your Citizenship. Some countries do not need a Visa to Enter Morocco.
Please check this [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visa_policy_of_Morocco).